# How to disable specific rows in GridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I want to disable specific rows of GridView in VB.NET.

I have tried, but all rows got disabled.

```
For a As Integer = indexSelected To DataGridDefectProduct.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridDefectProduct.Rows(a).Enabled = False
Next
```

error in

`DataGridDefectProduct.Rows(a).Enabled = False`

Please suggest if there is any alternative ways to do this.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve?  There is no `Enabled` property on a `DataGridViewRow` so there's no such thing as disabling a row.  Are you trying to prevent a user editing data in that row?  If so then the `ReadOnly` property is what you want.  In future, please explain WHAT you want to achieve, not just HOW you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: may i know what is your target of this code segment? hope that you want to make the grid cells in read only mode(not allowed to type),isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

- you have to change the `ReadOnly` property of your `Row`

  ```
  For a As Integer = indexSelected To DataGridDefectProduct.Rows.Count - 1
    DataGridDefectProduct.Rows(a).ReadOnly = False
  Next
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There does however appear to be a gridviewrow enabled property

```
Private Sub gv_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        If Mode = "View" Then
            e.Row().Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This disable the row from editing or deleting but allowed pagination to still work in view mode