# Trying to disable few items in a ListBox c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to disable a few items dynamically from a Listbox.  I used the following code:
[How To Disable Selected Item In List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090317/how-to-disable-selected-item-in-list-box)
But, all I see is System.Data.DataRow in the Listbox, not the actual string.

I tried adding new BindingContext()

```
lbInsTypes.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

Also,

```
lbInsTypes.DataBindings.Add("DisplayMember", dtInsType, "InsuranceDescription", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

but nothing worked.

```
DataSet dsInsType = db.GetAllInsuranceTypes(InstutionId);
lbInsTypes.DisplayMember = "InsuranceDescription";
lbInsTypes.ValueMember = "InsuranceTypeId";
lbInsTypes.DataSource = dsInsType.Tables[0];
```

I want to see the actual InsuranceDescription values in the ListBox from the table. Please show me how to use datasource with custom ListBox control.

Comment: The ListBox is not a good choice to view enabled/disabled items. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901494/how-to-disable-specific-rows-in-gridview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718338/disable-listview-item-in-vb-net) for better choices. However, everything is possible.